# Mule REST Component Return type

Tags: java, rest, jersey, mule, mule-component

I am trying to implement the REST component in Mule Flow and I was able to expose REST services also and the response is coming back to client also. But When I put Mule Java Component to access the properties of the REST component response, I am not able to do that. Below is the code of my Mule message processor,

```
public class RestResponseProcessor implements Callable{

@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    Object messagePayload = eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();
    System.out.println("Message payload class is  " + messagePayload.getClass());
    org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent jerseyResponse = (org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent) messagePayload;
    System.out.println("jerseyResponse.getClass() is  " + jerseyResponse.getClass());
    return eventContext;
}

}
```

The output for the first sysout is 
`Message payload class is  class org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent$2` but when I trying to cast it `org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent` object, it is giving classCastException, `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent$2 cannot be cast to org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent` 
What does this $2 means after the class name and what can be the  possible solution to this.

Basically I am trying to route my message based on the REST component response before sending the response to client.

Hope I am clear with my question.

Comment: XML config? Mule version?

Comment: I guess You already got an answer here :- http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/rest-component-return-type

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary Yes I got the answer and also have posted here as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from Mule forum.

$2 is an anonymous class of type org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler created by the Jersey component.

I tried using "Byte Array To String" and it worked. It solved my purpose.